# Calculate selling price to achieve at least 10% profit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to run a loop in an SQL query. My query looks at `[PROFIT_MARGIN]` to ensure the `%PROFIT` is above `10%` (in this case).

But some figures are below 10 or produce a minus figure, so I need to increase the price until the `[PROFIT_MARGIN]` reaches a more favorable point.

```
SELECT [RRP], [COST], [PROFIT], ([PROFIT/RRP]*100) AS [PROFIT_MARGIN],
       CASE WHEN ([PROFIT/RRP]*100) > 10 
            THEN RRP
            ****** OH NO THE PROFIT IS LESS THAN 10, WE NEED TO INCREASE THE RRP UNTIL SUCH A POINT THAT THE PROFIT_MARGIN is EQUAL to 10 THEN SET THE PRICE TO THAT NEW FIGURE ******
       END AS [PRICE]
FROM SOME_TABLE
```

**Some Sample Data**

```
RRP   Cost   Profit  Profit Margin
25    8      17      68
5.95  7.08   -1.13   -18.9915966387
17    13.02  3.98    23.4117647059
1.85  4.57   -2.72  -147.027027027
2.3   4.74   -2.44   -106.0869565217
2.65  5.02   -2.37   -89.4339622642
```

My guess is that I need to artificially increase the `[RRP]` until such a point that the end `[PROFIT_MARGIN]` column hits `10%`.

My approach, might be wrong in the requirement for the loop, I'm no SQL Pro.

Comment: If you would add sample data and expected result your question will be answered much faster.

Comment: As per my understanding, you want to increase RRP, to reach profit larger or equal 10%. So, you need to calculate Cost to RRP instead Profit to RRP. New RRP must be Cost + 10%. Am i right?

Comment: Maciej Los - Yes you are correct, the other answers are not and miss the point.  This needs to be a SELECT Query, not an UPDATE or an INSERT.  I just need to increase the RRP to a point WHERE the PROFIT MARGIN is = to 10, so I guess keep looping until it finds that point.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use a loop for something of this nature.

Your basic check requires that profit should be at least 10%, so you simply have to check if the profit margin is < 10%, and increase the selling price otherwise.

Here's a sample with the above data that you can execute as is:

```
CREATE TABLE #SOME_TABLE
    (
      [RRP] NUMERIC ,
      [Cost] NUMERIC ,
      [Profit] NUMERIC ,
      [Profit_Margin] NUMERIC
    );

INSERT  INTO #SOME_TABLE
        ( [RRP], [Cost], [Profit], [Profit_Margin] )
VALUES  ( 25, 8, 17, 68 ),
        ( 5.95, 7.08, -1.13, -18.9915966387 ),
        ( 17, 13.02, 3.98, 23.4117647059 ),
        ( 1.85, 4.57, -2.72, -147.027027027 ),
        ( 2.3, 4.74, -2.44, -106.0869565217 ),
        ( 2.65, 5.02, -2.37, -89.4339622642 );

DECLARE @MinProfitMargin INT = 10

SELECT  RRP ,
        Cost ,
        Profit ,
        Profit_Margin ,
        CASE WHEN Profit_Margin < @MinProfitMargin 
             THEN Cost * 1.1
             ELSE RRP
        END AS RRPor10PercentProfit
FROM    #SOME_TABLE

DROP TABLE #SOME_TABLE
```

**The Output:**

```
RRP Cost    Profit  Profit_Margin   RRPor10PercentProfit
25  8       17      68              25.0
6   7       -1      -19             7.7
17  13      4       23              17.0
2   5       -3      -147            5.5
2   5       -2      -106            5.5
3   5       -2      -89             5.5
```

The final column `RRPor10PercentProfit` shows you the current `RRP` if it achieves at least 10% profit, otherwise it shows you the value required to achieve 10% profit. This is calculated in this section of the code:

```
-- is the Profit_Margin less than my variable (10%)
CASE WHEN Profit_Margin < @MinProfitMargin 
     -- if so add 10% to cost price
     THEN Cost * 1.1
     -- otherwise give me the RRP
     ELSE RRP
END AS RRPor10PercentProfit
```

Comment: `RRP = Cost * 1.1` - that's what i suggested. Great minds thinking the same ;)

Comment: down vote? really? please explain what's wrong with this if anything?

Comment: It wasn't me. I upvoted your answer, very good answer! [EDIT] Please, see my answer.

Comment: @MaciejLos it's ok, I didn't suspect you. I've had a few rouge down votes in the last few days, think somebody might have a target on me.

Comment: Pure hate is hard to cure... Sad, but true.

Comment: Sorry Guys, but you have missed the point completely here.  This needs to be a SELECT Query, not an UPDATE or an INSERT.  I just need to increase the RRP to a point WHERE the PROFIT MARGIN is = to 10, so I guess keep looping until it finds that point.

Comment: @Stuart my answer provides a select query? have you run the code block to check the output? the insert is just used to populate a temp table for testing purposes.

Comment: OH!!! What an idiot am I trying to over complicate such a simple thing.  Thanks Tanner.

Comment: Actually I retract my comment about simplicity. Increasing the price by Multipling the cost price by 1.1 is NOT the same as calculating the Margin Difference.  I have found instances where this becomes even less.  It needs to be a calculated MARGINAL Increase not Cost+ or RRP+

Answer (score 3):

Please, read my comment to the question and see the solution provided by [Tanner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57475/tanner).

So, if you want to update `RRP`, use `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE t1 SET [RRP] = t2.[COST] *1.1
FROM tableName t1 INNER JOIN tableName t2 ON t1.PKey = t2.PKey
WHERE (t1.[RRP]/t1.[COST]) < 1.1
```

Thanks Tanner, for your valuable comment ;)

Comment: Sorry, but you have missed the point completely here. This needs to be a SELECT Query, not an UPDATE or an INSERT. I just need to increase the RRP to a point WHERE the PROFIT MARGIN is = to 10, so I guess keep looping until it finds that point.

Comment: @Stuart, i think i didn't miss anything. "Increase" means change original value. Finally, i wrote: "If you want to update...". Cheers, Maciej

Comment: I think your where clause is incorrect: `(t1.[COST]/t1.[RRP]*100)` - e.g. (5/5)*100 = 100. So if cost price = RRP it wouldn't be updated.

Comment: YES YOU ARE RIGHT, I am a moron, I have completely tried to over engineer, the simplicity though me right off. Thank you.

Comment: Actually I retract my comment about simplicity.  Increasing the price by Multipling the cost price by 1.1 is NOT the same as calculating the Margin Difference.

Comment: @Stuart, imagine that: Profit_Margin for RRP =25 and Cost=8 is equal to 17, which means 25-8=17. Profit_margin calculated for the second record is less then zero. So, you'll never reach Profit_Margin at least equal to 10, because every number times value less then zero is always will give you less then zero. Try this (second row RRP=5,95): (12000/7.08)*100=-0.009416667 ;) Conclusion: Profi_Margin is Cost times 1.1 ;)